# Does trigger.io have an API to store sensitive data?

Tags: trigger.io

I need to store sensitive data like an OAuth refresh token.
Is there an API in trigger.io to store data in an encrypted and secure way?

Answer (score 1):

The [prefs API](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/prefs.html) uses the native device storage which should be well compartmentalised between apps.

We'd be open to adding a layer of encryption there, but it's not immediately obvious how to do it in a sensible way: in order to be able to decrypt data on the client side, we'd need to store the key locally. Storing encrypted data and decryption key in the same place is not a good idea!

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use keychain on iOS?

Comment: Quite possibly, yes: as far as I'm aware there's nothing equivalent for Android, however...
KeyStore (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) requires a manual unlock step from the user.

Comment: Any plans on adding this to trigger.io? This is kind of essential to be able to store an OAuth refresh token.

Comment: Application-level data separation is enforced by the OS when using our prefs API: is that not sufficient for your needs with refresh tokens? Although we would like to support encrypted storage, we would need to have a good solution on all our supported platforms before we'd roll it out on one.

Comment: That's not secure enough since you can easily get to that data by rooting the device. I would be ok with an iOS solution only for the time being or the other approach would be to allow plugins for trigger.io.

Comment: Trigger.io now supports native plugins (http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/10/11/trigger-io-native-plugins-beta/). And they're most kindly offering revenue sharing on your released plugins.